# Ember.js - Where to put dropdown options?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a field in our DB that's a integer referring to a billing source. It can be 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4. This grew over time b/c originally was just 2 options. We have a Ruby class that handles this on the old frontend, something like this...

```
  module BillingSources
    Internal = 0
    Other = 1
    Other2 = 2
    Other3 = 3
  end
```

Where is the appropriate place to put the mapping of IDs to display in Ember.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method I find good for storing static values in EmberJS:

https://github.com/NetworkActionGroup/nagadmin/blob/master/app/initializers/load-static-models.js

Answer (score 1):

You can put these in an array inside your controller. If you have key-value pairs, you can use an array of objects. Inside your template you would then use `optionValueBinding` and `optionLabelBinding`.

Comment: I saw that option and that works for something like `app/controllers/accounts/edit.js`. Let's then say i want a helper like `billing-source` for my `app/controllers/accounts.index.hbs`. It'll now get the integer from the API and I'd like to translate that to the display name. Seems like the helper would duplicate this same mapping. In this case, is there a better place to keep this? It feels like a non-API backed model or something.

Comment: If the data has a global meaning, you could also define it as a constant I presume. Do you have a model in which this value is used, say `bill.source`? You could include the key-value pairs there, and have both controllers use that value.